# HQL querying issue in One to Many Case

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, hql

I have a table Users and another table called Transactiopn. One user has multiple transaction. I'm trying to write an HQL to get the list of all Users and his latest transaction.

How do I write this? Latest transaction means the one with max value of id.

If I write something like

```
select name, transaction.amount from Users
```

I get an error

**illegal attempt to dereference collection [{synthetic-alias}{non-qualified-property-ref}trIP Attribute] with element property reference**

this is because transaction is a list in User table. I need to select from Users itself since there are other related referenced columns. So how do I take the last transaction amount?

I can try to translate a normal SQL query if someone can help me with that.

Answer (score 0):

The JPA spec states that the select clause cannot contain collection-valued attributes. The error you are getting reflects that.

To select the contents of a collection, introduce an id variable to your query:

`select u.name, tr.amount from Users u JOIN u.transactions tr`

Comment: where do I use the id attribute.?

Comment: the `tr` is the id variable for the transactions collection, like `u` is for the Users